# when passing parameters to python/opencv function, giving parameters' name and not lead to different results, why

Tags: python, opencv

here:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

im = cv2.imread('eye.png')
im_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(im_gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 100, 100, 30, 120, 180)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(im_gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 100, param1=100, param2=30, minRadius=120, maxRadius=180)
```

Two function calls of `cv2.HoughCircles` get different results, the first one detect no circle but the second one gets a circle. Why?

Also, in opencv documentation, here is the function expression:

> cv2.HoughCircles(image, method, dp, minDist[, circles[, param1[,
>   param2[, minRadius[, maxRadius]]]]]) → circles

What do these brackets mean?

Comment: @xyres While a component of the question might be related, overall I think the issue is the mixture of positional and named parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brackets indicate the inside is optional.

Based on this documentation:

> cv2.HoughCircles(image, method, dp, minDist[, circles[, param1[, param2[, minRadius[, maxRadius]]]]]) → circles

Your first call is using these parameters, leaving out `maxRadius`:

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(
  im_gray,            # image
  cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, # method
  1,                  # dp
  100,                # minDist
  100,                # circles
  30,                 # param1
  120,                # param2
  180                 # minRadius
                      # maxRadius
)
```

Your second call is using these parameters, leaving out `circles`:

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(
  im_gray,            # image
  cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, # method
  1,                  # dp
  100,                # minDist
                      # circles
  param1=100,         # param1
  param2=30,          # param2
  minRadius=120,      # minRadius
  maxRadius=180       # maxRadius
)
```